# CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm running a CMake build script for a project on CentOS 6 and I'm getting the following errors:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
QT_QTOPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
  used as include directory in directory /home/auser/Documents/Projects/Framework/src/AFrameworkFolder
QT_QTWEBKIT_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
  used as include directory in directory /home/auser/Documents/Projects/Framework/src/BFrameworkFolder
```

I have QT 4.8.4 installed and I'm using CMake version 2.8.10.2. The build script I'm using also works fine on Mac OSX 10.8.

Can anyone tell me what is happening here?

To me it looks like its having trouble finding some of the QT folders it needs and I don't see any folders in QT mentioning OpenGL or Webkit. If these are missing how would I go about installing them? If this is not the issue can someone please guide me to fixing the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the folders for OpenGL and Webkit were missing. I just had to redownload a clean copy of QT and run through the installation directions here to install it: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-x11.html

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the actual `CMakeLists.txt`, but make sure you're finding your QtOpenGL correctly. That is, be sure your discovery asks for the required Qt modules, like this:

```
set(QT_USE_QTOPENGL 1)
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Didn't post the CMakeList.txt as its part of a framework so it actually has many parts, too much to include it all. However it does have the part you are describing. Also, it works fine on Mac OSX. Also, on CentOS it can find other QT directories fine (QT_INCLUDE_DIR & QT_QTCORE_INCLUDE_DIR). Its just seems to be the two QT directories mentioned in the error message that it cannot find.

Answer (score 0):

Install qtwebkit-devel RPM will solve it.