# Kate Cmake error

Tags: cmake, kate

I am trying to build Kate on Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.1 64-bit. I downloaded Kate source code and tried to install it according to http://kate-editor.org/get-it/. Now while trying to compile, I am getting cmake error.

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:

QT_QTOPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
used as include directory in directory /home/jaydipc/kde/kate/addons/kate/pate/sip
used as include directory in directory /home/jaydipc/kde/kate/addons/kate/pate/src
used as include directory in directory /home/jaydipc/kde/kate/addons/kate/pate/src
used as include directory in directory /home/jaydipc/kde/kate/addons/kate/pate/src/test

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Which commands did you call ? Only `cmake ..` ? Did you try to call `ccmake ..` to set options and configure ? I don't know Kate, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: As I said, I followed "Building Kate from Sources" from  kate-editor.org/get-it/. I used: cmake .. -DBUILD_KTEXTEDITOR=1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo \
              -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/kde/usr \
              -DINSTALL_PYTHON_FILES_IN_PYTHON_PREFIX=OFF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume You have Qt4 development packages installed in Your system and only missing `libqt4-opengl-dev`. So, the bluntest solution would be just install it. For example like this:

`$ sudo apt-get install libqt4-opengl-dev`

Relevant issue on MacOS: 
[CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15949153/1150918)

Comment: Thanks! That solves the opengl problem. Kate compiled and built successfully. But it crashes everytime at start. But that's a different problem. I shall post another question about the crash. Thanks again. +1